# React Router useNavigate hook unwanted scroll to the top onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, reach-router

I am adding url parameters as so using the Reach router library.
`import { useNavigate } from '@reach/router'`

`const navigate = useNavigate()`

Then I am using the qs library to add query parameters to the url as so

```
const handleSliderChange = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const params = location.search.slice(1)
  const paramsObj = qs.parse(params)
  paramsObj.date = newValue
  const paramsStr = qs.stringify(paramsObj)
  navigate(`/?${paramsStr}`, { replace: true })
  setSliderValue(newValue)
}
```

This works well for adding the query parameters but the page scrolls to the top. How do I stop this default behaviour?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `navigate` if you're not the URL or changing pages. Just use `window.history.replaceState()` directly.

Comment: Thanks @coreyward I did `window.history.replaceState('', '', '?'+paramsStr)` - seems to work well so far